# is possible to use django rest framework for a build APK?

Tags: django, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working with `django rest framework` my link is this: http://hernancapcha.webfactional.com/licencias/

and for `angular` and `IONIC` local works Ok but when I build my `APK` I got one error:

> http failure response for  0 unknown error

I understand that is because the headers in django, but is there a way to communicate both?

This is my Service:

```
getOneLicencia(pet): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/milistac/lice/?q=' + pet + '', {headers: this.httpHeaders});
}
```